# Little Doubt in Secant Method

Tags: numerical-methods

Given Question is :

A root of equation $xe^{x}-1=0$ lies in interval $(0.5,1.0)$. Determine this root correct to three decimal places using secant method

**DOUBT**

I know method, but my problem is how do i obtain error at first place?

Comment: There is a typo, maybe you mean $(0.5,1)$.   Error in first place? There is a sign change, so the initial error is less than $0.5$.  In practice the error estimate is not all that useful, when you think you are close enough (two successive estimates close) you can verify you are close by a sign change calculation, it it is not a double root.

Comment: My textbook writes error=0.0005 and reason it gives is since we want root correct to three decimal places. I didn't understand this. Why not 0.0004 or something?

Comment: Correct to $3$ decimal places means absolute value of the error is $\lt 5\times 10^{-4}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas how did you get that?

Comment: That is the definition of correct to $3$ decimal places. Think in terms of rounding. Anything in the interval $(0.678-.0005, 0.678+0.0005)$ rounds to $0.678$.